Why don't Arch maintainers sign their kernels/bootloaders?
I have just finished setting up secure boot in an Arch install. Unlike other distros this is not working out of the box. Nevertheless, the process to create your own keys and set up signing every kernel update with them automagically with the help of sbctl and a pacman hook is relatively simple.
I have an issue with this approach though: If I have to keep my keys on my machine, and I can use them to sign anything with credentials available to a tool I can invoke on userspace... How does that protect my system at all?
I would find it way more convenient and safe if these things were already signed by Arch maintainers. I could then just add their key to my secure boot database by allowing it on bios settings (or Microsoft-signed shim database like other distros do, I don't care), once. But I find no way of doing that. Why are all the methods of setting this up I see online so convoluted, when this solution seems so obvious and straight-forward? Is there a technical, ideological, or procedural reason I am missing?

Update: For anyone wanting to explore this topic even further, I've also found this blog post quite interesting and informative.


Why don't Arch maintainers sign their kernels/bootloaders?

Mainly because they do not currently have suitable infrastructure to store and access a signing key.
Unlike those other distributions, Arch packages are not currently built on a central "build farm" – the build is done manually, either on developers' own machines, or offloaded to an ordinary build server via SSH. The packages are then signed using the developer's own PGP key (and are delivered with that signature, not re-signed).
(The .iso images are built in a similar way – note how they're signed by a person's PGP key and not a generic "Debian buildd" key, and when that person is unavailable, sometimes the entire process is delayed.)
So far this has met the needs of package signing, because pacman has a procedure for key revocation (developer keys can be removed while retaining the same CAs), as well as the "M of N" trust model native to PGP. But mapping this model 1:1 to Secure Boot signing (assuming you only want internal "Arch CA" signing) would no longer allow automatic certificate revocation, as the only 'dbx' updates that can be installed automatically are those signed by Microsoft (because only Microsoft is in your 'KEK' list and there's no guarantee your machine's firmware will let you enroll a custom KEK without fully doing your own Secure Boot signing down from the PK anyway).
It also doesn't meet the requirements for "full" Secure Boot (the way other distributions do it), as the kernel needs to be signed by a single key that needs to be embedded into a Microsoft-signed build of the 'Shim' loader. To avoid the risk of key leaks (and Shim revocations/rebuilds/re-signing), there needs to be some kind of central build infrastructure, which is still very much in the process of being built itself, and ideally some kind of secure key storage (TPM or smartcard or Nitrokey or similar HSM) that would prevent the key from being extracted, which requires arrangements with the hosting company (Arch does not have its own datacenters).

If I have to keep my keys on my machine, and I can use them to sign anything with credentials available to a tool I can invoke on userspace...

This is the same situation as in Ubuntu, for example, which also has you store a key on your machine – the MOK (Machine Owner Key) – that can be used to sign any kernel module, both legitimate (DKMS packages) and not.
(From what I remember, it also comes with an EFI program that lets someone with physical access enroll any MOK they want, though most firmwares allow that for Secure Boot anyway.)

How does that protect my system at all?

Secure Boot on its own doesn't protect your system much (if at all), in the first place – especially considering that it doesn't even validate the initrd image (indeed unless the local 'UKI' signing process is used). 90% of its usefulness comes from being used in combination with encryption of the system disk (which also means your signing keys will also be encrypted).
Indeed with most Linux distributions, the secure chain straight up stops at the kernel and its modules and does nothing to prevent external tampering of even the most critical userspace files – only the fact that the disk is encrypted happens to mostly prevent that.
To be most useful, Secure Boot needs to be combined with measured boot – for example, where the disk encryption keys are sealed using the TPM and bound to specific system state. That's what BitLocker does; its auto-unlock doesn't want "Secure Boot pass", it wants "Secure Boot says the Windows kernel was signed by this MS certificate specifically", i.e. it becomes an ingredient in the overall system state attestation.
(DRM & anticheat systems also use SB TPM measurements without disk encryption.)
There are some parallels to how TLS and SSH work: first the encryption keys are exchanged in an unauthenticated way (DH), and only later the server's private key is used to bind the certificate and the transcript of the previous process; this means DH is a critical part of the protocol yet would be nearly useless on its own.


It also doesn't meet the requirements for "full" Secure Boot ... signed by a single key that needs to be embedded into a Microsoft-signed build of the 'Shim' loader -> That's my point, shim or not, just an "Arch distro" key that I can add to the boot loader db; From what you say about their infrastructure/release process I can see how that is not possible for them, so I understand now.



Secure Boot on its own doesn't protect your system much (if at all), in the first place -> on its own, of course.



_ 90% of its usefulness comes from being used in combination with encryption of the system disk_ -> And I am fine with that



(which also means your signing keys will also be encrypted) -> As far as I understand, TPM can handle that as you mention; or maybe just use a passphrase encrypted key that is input manually on every boot for disk decryption, like luks typically does. But that can be a separate, user key held in the system, whereas the "distro key" still protects the kernel & bootloader from a bad actor after they gain access; because it is not held within the system (If I understand it correctly). So I see value on having it as well.


*because it is not held within the system - > IDK why Ubuntu does it that way?

The bad actor needs root access to get at the key, and with root access there are many more avenues for tampering – kernel and bootloader doesn't really cover much. But consider that Ubuntu has the MOK key so that you would be able to install custom modules (e.g. NVIDIA driver or broadcom-wl as a DKMS module), so it necessarily has to be available to root in order to be useful. The end goal of SB usage (by Linux distros) is not to protect the system from its admin; instead things like AppArmor or Flatpak would try to prevent programs from getting those root privileges, I suppose.

Indeed there are more avenues for tampering and perhaps other hardening mechanisms (SELinux, suricata, clamav?) that require more fiddling than a checkbox on install and/or a key addition to the SB. I consider those overkill for a personal system, but I see your point now: Without them ("distro signed" ) SB does not do much; With them it seems superfluous.
